# How can I perform filter and join in a Slick Scala query?

Tags: scala, filter, left-join, slick, slick-3.0

I have a providerTable(providerId, active, ….) and a reviewTable(reviewKey, providerId, …). Please note that the providerId is kind of foreign key here.
I need to fetch the reviews of active providers. So I am joining these two tables and filtering based on the flag ‘active’, can someone help me figure the right syntax? Thanks. Below is what I tried:

```
  val rTable = TableQuery[ReviewTable]
  val pTable = providerDao.table

  def findReviewForActiveProviders()(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Seq[Review]] = dbRun {
    rTable
      .joinLeft(pTable filter (_.active))
      .on(_.providerId === _.providerId)
      .result
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need reviews only for active providers, you'll need inner join, rather than left. Didn't tested but query should looks like below:

```
val joinQuery = for {
  (review, provider) <- rTable join ptable.filter(_.active) on (_.providerId === _.providerId)
} yield (reviews)

dbRun {
    joinQuery.result
}
```